# $\phi(A) =(I_n-A)(I_n+A)^{-1}$ is antisymmetric?

Tags: lie-groups

Let $U=\{A\in SO_n(\mathbb R)/ \;\det(I_n+A)\neq0\}$. Let $\phi :U\to M_n(\mathbb R)$ the application defined by : $$\phi(A)=(I_n-A)(I_n+A)^{-1}$$
How can I show that $\phi(A)$ is antisymmetric !?

Any help is highlty appreciated!

Comment: You showed $\phi(A)^2 = I$? It is strange. If $A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ then it seems $\phi(A) = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, and $\phi(A)^2 = -I$, unless I misunderstood something.

Comment: I edit my question. It's me who misunderstood something !

Comment: See [Cayley Transform](https://lcvmwww.epfl.ch/teaching/modelling_dna/index.php?dir=exercises&file=corr03.pdf)

Comment: thanks a lot for your help ! @JeanMarie

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthi The matrix you wrote is not orthogonal by dint of its bad normalization.

Comment: @Zach Teitler Your *A* is not normalized to be orthogonal, which makes all the difference.

Comment: My matrix is extremely orthogonal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $A$ is orthogonal, $AA^T = I$.
Set $\phi = (I-A)(I+A)^{-1}$,
so
$$
\begin{split}
  \phi^T &= ((I+A)^{-1})^T (I-A)^T \\
  &= (I+A^T)^{-1} (I-A^T) \\
  &= (I+A^{-1})^{-1} (I-A^{-1}) \\
  &= (A^{-1}(A+I))^{-1} (A^{-1}(A-I)) \\
  &= (A+I)^{-1}AA^{-1}(A-I).
\end{split}
$$
Here, all the factors commute with each other because they just involve $A$ and $I$.
From this, you can finish the steps to show that $\phi^T = -\phi$.
So $\phi$ is antisymmetric.

Answer (score 1):

You are writing down an inverse [Cayley transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_transform) which is   *its own inverse: an involution*. You may check all inverses below are nonsingular. Your matrices *A* are orthogonal (rotation) matrices by definition. The Cayley transform maps antisymmetric to orthogonal matrices, [and](https://planetmath.org/cayleysparameterizationoforthogonalmatrices) hence orthogonal to antisymmetric ones. You might be interested in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/705408/geometry-of-the-cayley-transform).

Since the left and right factor of what you write commute because both terms in each do, you can write
$$
\phi= \frac{I-A}{I+A},  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~A A^T=I, \leadsto \\
A=  \frac{I-\phi}{\phi +I}, ~~~~~~~~~~~~~    \frac{I-\phi}{I+\phi} \frac{I-\phi^T}{I+\phi^T}=I \leadsto \\
 \frac{I-\phi}{I+\phi}=  \frac{I+\phi^T}{I-\phi^T}  ~. 
$$
Cayley-transforming both sides again, you conclude that $\phi^T= -\phi$. This is why you had to show the transform is an involution.

Reassure yourself no denominator vanishes. Try a simple [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_transform#Examples), e.g.
$$
A= \tfrac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt 3 & -1\\1& \sqrt 3  \end{bmatrix}, ~~~~~~~I-A= \tfrac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}2-\sqrt 3 & 1\\-1&2- \sqrt 3  \end{bmatrix},\\
(I+A)^{-1}= \frac{1}{4+2\sqrt3}\begin{bmatrix}2+\sqrt 3 & 1\\-1&2+ \sqrt 3  \end{bmatrix}\\ \implies \phi= \frac{1}{2+\sqrt 3}\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\-1&0   \end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Are you trying to say that $(I-X)/(I+X) = (I-Y)/(I+Y) \implies X=Y$? How do you justify something like that?

Comment: By Cayley-transforming both sides. In physics one rarely fusses the uniqueness of the transform's inverse.

Comment: Okay, thanks. (As a mathematician I am uncomfortable just ignoring whether a transform's inverse is unique, but, okay.)